# To split multiple sheets in an excel to multiple csv files

Tags: excel, csv

I have a single Excel containing many sheets as sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, etc. I need to split this Excel into individual CSVs, i.e.

> sheet1--->file1.csv
>
> sheet2-->file2.csv
>
> sheet3-->file3.csv
>
> and so
>   on...

I need to do this either using PERL or UNIX. I also want to know the record count from each of the individually generated CSVs.

Since I am a beginner in Unix, I spent much time in writing the code and it doesn't seem working.
Please give your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you do it in Excel?

Comment: If you have code, you should post it, even if it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I guess this post (link) should help you.[Batch split xls sheets to csv](http://cwestblog.com/2011/05/05/excel-batch-convert-xls-to-csv/) -
This contains a js code which you just have to put inside the folder where you have all the xls files.It will split the sheets into separate csv and name them following this syntax: `{file_name}-{worksheet_name}.csv`
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `csvkit` program:

```
in2csv --write-sheets "-" -f Masterfile.xlsx
```

which will generate as many files as they are sheets

> Masterfile_0.csv Masterfile_1.csv ...

or you can also use the `ssconvert` tool from the Gnumeric project:

```
ssconvert -S Masterfile.xlsx split_file.csv
```

but the naming scheme is less convenient as each file have the sheet number prepended (they need to be renamed):

> split_file.csv.0 split_file.csv.1